# In a Windows Form, a combobox contains the items, but they are not visible (possible issue with a DisplayMember)

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

The issue is as follows:

I have this form that deals with locations, it has a text field for city name and a combobox with country names. That forms works fine - country items are displayed correctly.

Now I have this other form which is to contain a list of all cities to choose from. The mechanism is the same:

```
    // .... THIS IS PART OF THE WORKING FORM - COMBO WITH COUNTRY ITEMS

    private void frmManageCity_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindCountry();
        cmbCityCountry.SelectedValue = selectedCountryId;
    }

    private void BindCountry()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = countryService.GetResponse();

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            cmbCityCountry.DataSource = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Country>>().Result;
            cmbCityCountry.ValueMember = "Id";
            cmbCityCountry.DisplayMember = "Name";
        }
    }
```

... and this is the code of non-working combo in another form:

```
    private void frmLodgingManage_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindCity();
    }

    private void BindCity()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = cityService.GetResponse();

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            cmbLodgingCity.DataSource = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<City>>().Result;
            cmbLodgingCity.ValueMember = "Id";
            cmbLodgingCity.DisplayMember = "Name";
        }
    }
```

However, when I click to select an item from the combobox on this other form - the items are there, you can mouse hover over the items, they become blue and there is correct number of them -- but it's as they are color white on white background - no letters are visible at all. Also, when I to select any of them, I end up with only a cursor blinking at the beginning of the combobox, nothing gets selected.

### [image: Heading]

Since that combobox has a button on its right side to add a new city (if the desired city is not in the list), adding funcionality works as well - the count increases but items remain invisible.

Comment: Does your `City` class have a `Name` string property?

Comment: Yes, it does. See the screenshot: http://prntscr.com/g4zn8k

Comment: Do the deserialization in a separate step from the DataSource assignment so you can more easily debug and see your List. Does it deserialize properly?

Comment: @Crowcoder Actually I'm not very experienced in C# or WinForms so I don't really know what you mean? I might do some expoloration on deserialization you're mentioning and probably get back to you later.

Comment: I just mean do this: `List<City> cities = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<City>>().Result;` and then look at `cities` in debugger.

Comment: @Crowcoder Good advice. I'm receiving 8 objects but every attribute is either 0 (ints) or null (objects). For some reason either the API is not returning correct results or they get lost on the way.

Comment: Whatever is being returned is not in the schema of a `City`. Does `Content` have a `ReadAsStringAsync` method? If so you can look at the raw json or xml.

Comment: @Crowcoder As usual - a stupid mistake on OP's own part. I forgot my API actually returns list of (custom) CityVM objects (I need this to be able to create some other attributes in the response elsewhere).
Thank you for your debugging advice!